# change result when N++ in python loop

Tags: python, loops

i need to add N at loop like (n=0 n++ )until it stop to n=1000
i get all loop result  for A

```
def f(t):
  return(3*t**2+2)
N=1000
x1=1
x2=2
dx=(x2-x1)/N
A=0
x=x1
while x<=x2:
  dA=f(x)*dx
  A=A+dA

  x=x+dx
print("A = ",A)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need that?

Comment: to get all possible result to A

Comment: But what's wrong with the way you're already doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Try a for loop:

```
for i in range(100):
     # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `range(N)` and some other changes to get a more accurate result:

```
from statistics import mean

def f(t):
  return(3 * t**2 + 2)

N = 1000
x1 = 1
x2 = 2

Dx = x2 - x1
A = mean(f(x)
         for i in range(N)
         for x in [x1 + Dx * (i+0.5) / N]) * Dx
print("A = ", A)
```

That prints `8.99999975`, whereas yours prints `9.009500499999444`. The mathematically correct result would be [t^3+2t]_1^2 = (2^3+2*2)-(1^3+2*1) = 12-3 = 9.